# How to hide the owner date etc on properties in pdf document

Tags: pdf, properties, hide

Wanting to create a pdf that the receiver can not see who wrote and when it was created. How to do?? Im not very literate on pdf!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`exiftool`](https://exiftool.org/) to strip the metadata from PDF file. It run under Windows, Linux, etc. The command is:

```
exiftool -all= name_of_pdf_file.pdf
```

The software create backup of original file under name: `name_of_pdf_file.pdf_original`